# What is the equivalent of record-gcc-switches for Visual Studio compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to validate that the flags I'm setting using CMake are indeed the same flags that are used to compile a binary. Apparently there is a `-frecord-gcc-switches` that can be used with gcc but I cannot find the equivalent for other compilers, specifically Visual Studio. Is there a flag that would help me find the compile flags of a binary compiled with Visual Studio?

*Edit*: If there is no such switch, is there any other way to find the compile flags from a binary?

Answer (score 0):

As I am aware of there is no such switch.